# Get distinct and unique user counts grouped by year and month with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
|User|Month|Year|
| 1  | 3   |2010|
| 1  | 4   |2010|
| 2  | 4   |2010|
| 3  | 5   |2010|
| 7  | 8   |2011|
| 3  | 5   |2011|
```

I just want to get distinct count of users according to month and years

For the example table,

```
2010 3.month has 1 user (user 1)
2010 4.month has 1 user (user 2) (not user 1 because its already registered in 3. month)
2010 5. month has 1 user (user 3)
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['Year', 'Month']).User.nunique()` would do it, I think.

Comment: I'm gonna try and notice you

Comment: Actually, after reading your question again, it may not, because it does not take those monthly duplicates into account. See my answer for a revised version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would solve it.
1.Take the first occurrence of each user
2.Groupby to get unique count

```
df.groupby('User').first().reset_index().groupby(['Year', 'Month'])['User'].nunique()
```

Out[98]:

```
 Year  Month
 2010  3        1
       4        1
       5        1
 2011  8        1
 Name: User, dtype: int64
```